# 'Nonclassical' abstract Wiener space

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Is it possible to construct an abstract Wiener space $(W,H,\mu)$ such that $C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)\subset H$ and $W$ is a normed function space such that the convergence in norm implies convergence in (Lebesgue) measure? The set $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

I know there exist Wiener spaces $(C[0,1],H^\alpha[0,1],\mu)$, with a fractional Sobolev space $H^\alpha$ with index $\alpha>1/2$, and the space $(H^{-\frac{d+1}{2}}(\Omega),L_2(\Omega),\mu)$. Is there anything in between? I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: A candidate  (in 1 dim) would be $H=H^{1/2}$, and the question seems to be whether the Gaussian Fourier series partial sums $\sum_1^N n^{-1/2}Z_n e^{inx}$ (with $Z_n$ i.i.d. complex Gaussian variables) converge in measure on $(0,2\pi)$. I would be surprised if it did! And the condition that $W$ be normed adds to the doubtfulness...

Comment: What you are asking is equivalent to squeezing Hilbert spaces $H$ in between $C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)$ and $C(\Omega^\prime)$ for subsets $\Omega^\prime$ of arbitrarily large measure. Indeed, whenever a Gaussian measure lives in $L^0$ its Cameron-Martin space has to consist of functions that are continuous on sets of large measure, and conversely, for any such Cameron-Martin space, the canonical Gaussian measure lives in $W := L^1(\mu^\prime)$ for some equivalent measure $\mu^\prime$.

Comment: My not-so-educated guess is that this is impossible because the embedding $C^\alpha \to C$ should only be $2$-summing for $\alpha > d/2$.

Comment: I have just had to roll back an edit from @AmirSagiv which changed the sense/intent of the original by implicitly reversing quantifiers: the question starts with $\Omega$ and asks to find $(W,H,\mu)$, while Amir's edit starts with $(W,H,\mu)$ and asked "does there exist $\Omega$". Amir, **please stop doing these kinds of edit** if you are not absolutely certain about the original intent and the English idiom!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a few (perhaps trivial) ideas.  (Please don't upvote this, because this question should stay "unanswered".)

- It's known that for any abstract Wiener space, the inclusion $H \subset W$ must be compact.  So we could ask the purely functional-analytic question: do there even exist a Hilbert space $H$ and a Banach space $W$ such that $C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega) \subset H \subset W \subset L^0(\Omega)$, where $L^0(\Omega)$ is the space of measurable functions on $\Omega$ with the topology of convergence in measure, all inclusions are continuous, and the inclusion $H \subset W$ is compact?  If not, this resolves the present question negatively.
- It's also known that any Hilbert–Schmidt operator on $H$ leads to a measurable norm, under which the completion $W$ admits a Gaussian measure $\mu$ whose Cameron-Martin space is $H$.    So we could ask: do there exist Hilbert spaces $H,W$ such that $C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega) \subset H \subset W \subset L^0(\Omega)$, where all inclusions are continuous and the inclusion $H \subset W$ is Hilbert–Schmidt?  If yes, this resolves the present question positively.
- I thought at first about trying to take $H = L^2(\Omega)$, but the compactness of $H \subset W$ rules this out, since one can find an $L^2$-bounded sequence for which no subsequence converges in measure (e.g. $f_n(x) = e^{inx}$).  Maybe this would rule out some other candidates for $H$ as well.

Comment: Your first idea, for a negative answer (which is my bet nevertheless) doesn't work, as the inclusion $H^s\subset L^2$ _is_ compact ($s>0$, $\Omega$ bounded) and $C^{0,1/2}\subset H^s$ for $s<\frac12$. (Besides, only for $s>\frac12$ -- if $\Omega\subset\mathbb R$ -- is the inclusion $H^s\subset L^2$ Hilbert-Schmidt, so that a positive answer cannot be that simple).

Comment: You could always make this answer CW...