# Various limits of the Christoffel Darboux Kernel

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orthogonal-polynomials, integral-kernel

In a [different thread](https://mathoverflow.net/a/236999/42864), we stumbled upon the following question:

Given a continuous finite measure $w(x)dx$ on some interval $(a,b)$, $-\infty \leq a <b \leq \infty$, and the set of respective orthogonal polynomials $\{p_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. We follow Szego and define the kernel as $$ K_N (t,x) = \sum\limits_{\nu =0}^N \bar{p_{\nu} }(t) p_{\nu}(x).$$

**Question 1:** Since for every polynomial $q$ of small enough a degree, we have $\int\limits_a^b K_N(t,x)q(t) \, dt = q(x)$, can say that $K_N(t,x)$ converges in $w^*$ topology? If so, that what is its limit?

**Edit:** In [Aronszajn (1950)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1990404.pdf?_=1461643206256), section 9, it seems clear that $K_n$ themselves converge in $L^2$ norm.

**Question 2:** If (1) is true, does $K_N$ converges in a stronger sense? pointwise, almost everywhere etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both questions receive some answers in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1990404.pdf?_=1461643206256).

In th $L^2$ norm, Section 9 seems to stipulate convergence and a limit $K$.

For the uniform and pointwise convergence, we have on p. 374, Theorem II, that since the orthogonal projections converge, we have *pointwise* convergence of $K_n(x,y)$ to $K$. Also, at least for some polynomial sets (Jacobi and Legendre specifically), we have uniform convergence of the projection, which implies uniform convergence of $K_n$.

**Edit:** After further searching, I've found out that this is the Christoffel-Darboux kernel. Here is a [broad survey](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/08/08-107.pdf) about this family of kernels.

Comment: I have left you a comment on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214402/nonclassical-abstract-wiener-space about an edit that I had to revert

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/posts/238148/revisions and http://mathoverflow.net/posts/238222/revisions